# Can std::forward_list members be implemented as static?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

`std::forward_list` provides `insert_after` and `erase_after` members which may not need to actually access the `std::forward_list` object. Therefore they can be implemented as `static` member functions and be called without a list object — useful for an object that wants to delete itself from a list, which is a very common use. **EDIT**: This optimization only applies to `forward_list` specializations on `std::allocator` or user-defined stateless allocators.

Can a standard-conforming implementation do this?

§17.6.5.5/3 says

> A call to a member function signature described in the C++ standard library behaves as if the implementation
>   declares no additional member function signatures.

with a footnote

> A valid C++ program always calls the expected library member function, or one with equivalent behavior. An implementation may also define additional member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program.

It's not clear to me whether adding `static` would create a "different" member function, but removing an (implicit) argument shouldn't break anything that adding defaulted arguments wouldn't, and that is legal. (You cannot legally take a PTMF to any standard member function.)

It strikes me that the library should be allowed to do this, but I'm not sure if some rule would be broken. And how normative are the listed member function prototypes?

Comment: Mutating list operations require access to the list's allocator, so I doubt they could be static (especially with the new stateful allocators).

Comment: Still, the template can be specialized for the extremely common case of `std::allocator` and likewise by the user for their own if desired.

Comment: How would you specialize this based on knowledge about the *iterator* alone? The iterator doesn't know to which list it belongs, nor which allocator that list uses.

Comment: @KerrekSB Given only the iterator, you would need to use call syntax specific to static member functions, which would be nonstandard. The template would be specialized on the knowledge that the allocator is `std::allocator` which is always stateless.

Comment: Related to this topic is an article by Scott Meyers, "[How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197)", a very good read.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's possible that the iterator is a subclass of the forward list, or otherwise knows the _type_ of the allocator, in which case it can create a new copy if the allocator is stateless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard says you can get away with it if no one can tell the difference.  And you are correct that one can not legally create a PTMF into `forward_list`, so you're safe that way.

The danger of custom allocators has already been pointed out.  But even for `std::allocator<T>` there is a danger that someone could specialize `std::allocator<MyType>` and then detect that the `allocator::construct/destroy` wasn't being called.

Okay, but can one specialize say `std::forward_list<int>` (no custom allocator, no user defined value_type) and make `insert_after` static?

No.  This change would be detectable with the new SFINAE capabilities.  Here is a demo:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class A = std::allocator<T>>
class forward_list
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    struct const_iterator {};
    struct iterator {};

    iterator insert_after(const_iterator p, const T& x);
};

template <class C>
auto test(C& c, typename C::const_iterator p, const typename C::value_type& x)
    -> decltype(C::insert_after(p, x))
{
    std::cout << "static\n";
    return typename C::iterator();
}

template <class C>
auto test(C& c, typename C::const_iterator p, const typename C::value_type& x)
    -> decltype(c.insert_after(p, x))
{
    std::cout << "not static\n";
    return typename C::iterator();
}

int main()
{
    ::forward_list<int> c;
    test(c, ::forward_list<int>::const_iterator(), 0);
}
```

This program runs and prints out:

```
not static
```

But if I make `insert_after` static:

```
static iterator insert_after(const_iterator p, const T& x);
```

Then I get a compile time error:

```
test.cpp:34:5: error: call to 'test' is ambiguous
    test(c, ::forward_list<int>::const_iterator(), 0);
    ^~~~
test.cpp:16:6: note: candidate function [with C = forward_list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >]
auto test(C& c, typename C::const_iterator p, const typename C::value_type& x)
     ^
test.cpp:24:6: note: candidate function [with C = forward_list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >]
auto test(C& c, typename C::const_iterator p, const typename C::value_type& x)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

**Difference detected.**

Thus it is non-conforming to make `forward_list::insert_after` static.

**Update**

If you want to make the "static" overload callable, you simply need to make it slightly more desirable than the "not static" overload.  One way of doing that is changing the "not static" overload to:

```
template <class C, class ...Args>
auto test(C& c, typename C::const_iterator p, const typename C::value_type& x, Args...)
    -> decltype(c.insert_after(p, x))
{
    std::cout << "not static\n";
    return typename C::iterator();
}
```

Now the test will print out either "static" or "not static" depending on whether the `insert_after` member function is static or not.

Comment: Hadn't thought about user-specialized `std::allocator`, great point. But isn't the `"static"` overload a template with no possible well-formed specialization, hence ill-formed with no diagnostic required?

Comment: Updated answer with fully functioning "static detector".

Comment: Okay... not to be difficult, but how is this different from, for example, detecting a default argument by finding the type of a non-overloaded member function? Now the template produces a valid specialization, but it still seems to be UB because the expression `C::insert_after()` is not defined by the standard. Likewise, is a variadic templated implementation of `Allocator::construct` non-compliant in C++03 because it can be called as `construct<>(...)`? This is really the jist of the original question, as to the depth of the library specification.

Comment: <shrug> Perhaps not at all.  Except that [member.functions]/p2 specifically gives permission for implementations to add (or subtract via overloads) default arguments to non-virtual member functions.  But there is no such permission given regarding making member functions static.  Our new SFINAE capabilities in C++11 are new even to committee members, and I have no doubt that we are all in for an education over the next 5 years.  No doubt the language and library will continue to evolve due to this continuing education.