# Using std::tuple_size on classes derived from std::array

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code that kinda looks like the following:

```cpp
#include <array>

class DoubleArray: std::array<double, 16> {
public:
    void clear() {
        fill(0.0);
    }
};
```

Now I would like to use the size of the `std::array` as a compile time constant. If `DoubleArray` was just a `typedef` to `std::array` I could use `std::tuple_size<DoubleArray>::value` but using inheritance instead I get the following compiler error:

```
error: incomplete type ‘std::tuple_size<DoubleArray>’ used in nested name specifier
```

I have seen [tuple_size and an inhereted class from tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967746/tuple-size-and-an-inhereted-class-from-tuple) but since that only talks about std::tuple I don't think it can be applied. Any ideas why this doesn't work and if there is an easy way to make it work?

Comment: If you are OK with it you can say `std::tuple_size<DoubleArray::array>::value`.

Comment: @litb Perfect, thanks! That was actually easier than I thought...

Comment: I don't see why the linked question doesn't also apply here. You could specialize tuple_size for your type, though personally I prefer Johannes's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `size()` - for arrays it is a `constexpr`.

See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size
or check § 23.3.2.1.3 where it is defined as `constexpr size_type size() noexcept;`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work since size() is not a static method and I don't have an instance of the class. DoubleArray::size() can't be called without an instance.

Comment: @Turbo: Why *isn't* it a static method? It doesn't change based on the instance, so there's no reason for it to be non-static.

Comment: @NicolBolas how is he supposed to answer that? Such questions are a matter of Standard interpretation. For a similar argument see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820981 . In this case, whether `array::size` is static or nonstatic is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I meant that he should make *his* `DoubleArray` class have a `static`, `constexpr` size method. Whether it's called `size` or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @NicolBolas That solves the problem at hand, but sacrifices backward compatibility with `array`. Sounds like he wants a uniform interface.

Comment: @NicolBolas Implementing a static constexpr size() method in my own class still wouldn't solve the problem, because that method would still need to know the size somehow. Unless I want to copy the size from the template arguments this approach only moved the problem into the new method.